# Error ~ Check if character is lowercase letter

Tags: c++, lowercase

This is the code that I had written to check whether [i] is a lowercase letter or not.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
       int i=0;
       char str[i]="Enter an alphabet:";
       char i;
       while(str[i])
            {
              i=str[i];
              if (islower(i))  i=toupper(i);
              putchar(i);
              i++;
            }
       return 0;
     }
```

The Error I m getting is

```
    ||=== Build: Debug in practice (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\krish\practice\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\krish\practice\main.cpp|9|error: conflicting declaration 'char i'|
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\krish\practice\main.cpp|7|note: previous declaration as 'int i'|
    ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't really need the `islower` check. [`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) returns the argument unmodified if it's not a lower-case letter.

Comment: And in the future, please try to actually *read* the error messages. The message is very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error message says: You declare `i` twice. Once as `char` and once as `int`.

```
int i=0; // declare i as int and assign 0
char str[i]="Enter an alphabet:";
char i; // declare i as char -> i is already declared as int.
```

Rename one of your variables.

Also don't use `conio.h` - it's not part of the standard C library nor is it defined by POSIX.

Comment: Which version of C++ allows a zero-size array?

Answer (score 1):

An array must have a constant size at compile time and a non-zero size:

```
int i = 0;
char str[i] = "Enter an alphabet:"; //
```

Above in your code `i` must be constant and must not be `0`.

so you can declare it like this:

```
const int SIZE = 50;
char str[SIZE] = "Enter an alphabet:";
```

ALso here:

```
char i;
while(str[i])
```

Above you used `i` without initializing it And you Used a `char` as an index of an Array!

Your code would look like:

```
    const int SIZE = 50; // constant size
    char str[SIZE] = "Enter an alphabet:";

    //if you want : char str[] = "Enter an alphabet:";

    int i = 0; // initialize
    while( i < strlen(str))
    {
        char c = str[i];
        if(islower(c))
            c = toupper(c);
        putchar(c);
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

New code~~~

```
    /* islower example */
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <ctype.h>
      int main ()
      {
       int i=0;
       char str[]="Test String.\n";
       char c;
       while (str[i])
        {
         c=str[i];
         if (islower(c)) c=toupper(c);
         putchar (c);
         i++;
        }
       return 0;
       }
```

now its working ~~